# Match relative values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I earlier posted it [here](http://www.msofficeforums.com/excel-programming/26216-how-compare-data-based-value-re-arrange.html) but did not find the answer.

Is it possible to compare any column with respect to specific reference column and if match found re-arrange the column with respect to reference column.

for example I have this.

```
10.0    10.1
10.2    12.4
10.4    13.5
10.6    14.4
10.8    
11.0    
11.2    
11.4    
11.6    
11.8    
12.0    
12.2    
12.4    
12.6    
12.8    
13.0    
13.2    
13.4    
13.6    
13.8    
14.0    
14.2    
14.4
```

and I want to convert it to this.

```
10.0    10.1
10.2    
10.4    
10.6    
10.8    
11.0    
11.2    
11.4    
11.6    
11.8    
12.0    
12.2    
12.4    12.4
12.6    
12.8    
13.0    
13.2    
13.4    13.5
13.6    
13.8    
14.0    
14.2    
14.4    14.4
```

or this

```
10.0    10.1    10.1
10.2    12.4    
10.4    13.5    
10.6    14.4    
10.8        
11.0        
11.2        
11.4        
11.6        
11.8        
12.0        
12.2        
12.4            12.4
12.6        
12.8        
13.0        
13.2        
13.4            13.5
13.6        
13.8        
14.0        
14.2        
14.4            14.4
```

which ever is feasible. Is this possible or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this **formula** in C2,

```
=IF(AGGREGATE(15, 6, B$2:B$5/(B$2:B$5>=A2), 1)<>AGGREGATE(15, 6, B$2:B$5/(B$2:B$5>=A3), 1), AGGREGATE(15, 6, B$2:B$5/(B$2:B$5>=A2), 1), "")
```

Fill down.

[image: stagger_IF]